# call bitcoind rpc api over docker

Tags: docker, rpc, docker-container, bitcoind, bitcoin-sv

I started my node container with this flags:

```
daemon=1
printtoconsole=1
testnet=1
rpcport=9332
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
server=1
```

I opened port in my `docker-compose` :

```
node:
    image: bitcoin-sv
    container_name: 'node'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9332:9332'
```

I can call methods from bitcoin-cli in my container

```
docker exec -it node bash
root@9196d074e4d8:/opt/bitcoin-sv# ./bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

But I cannot call it from curl

```
curl --user user --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo, "params": ["", 0.1, "donation", "seans outpost"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:9332
Enter host password for user 'user':
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

How can i call it from curl? Maybe i have to call to cli?

Comment: Yes I am also facing the same issue, @trololo were you able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

not sure what can be your issue, but the first approach would be do the curl inside the container in order to verify that the HTTP interface is working properly. So you should try this:

```
docker exec -it node bash
root@9196d074e4d8:/opt/bitcoin-sv# curl --user user --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo, "params": ["", 0.1, "donation", "seans outpost"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' localhost:9332
```

Once you are sure the interface is working inside the container, you can move forwred and try it from the host.